# How to instead "View inflate(int resource,ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)" method when the View just a Simple View used "new TextView"?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

When I use the Adapter of a *RecyclerView* to create *ViewHolder*, the view is just a *TextView*, so I don't want use `LayoutInflate.inflate()` with a *layout.xml* file. Therefore I create a *TextView* instance via constructor, but the *TextView* shows nothing. Now I want know if there is a way to solve this？

1. I write `parent.addView(textview)` before `return`, but it crashed.
2. When I write a *`layout.xml`* and use
   `LayoutInflate.from().inflate()`, it works well.

```
    @Override
    public GeekSearchWordItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, R.dimen.text_size_medium);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.text_c6));
        return new ViewHolder(textView);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GeekSearchWordItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        LevelBean bean = LList.getElement(mDatas, position);
        if (bean != null) {
            holder.mTxtName.setText(bean.name);
        }
    }
    ...
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTxtName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTxtName = (TextView) itemView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that `bean != null`?

Comment: Don't you have to explicit return `GeekSearchWordItemAdapter.ViewHolder` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onCreateViewHolder() try to add layout params to the TextView you creates there.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                 RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Add your xml file to the question, please.

Comment: And as psknik wrote, debug and check bean for null.